# Migrating Access DB using SQL Server Migration AssistantAWS SQL Server RDS instance . I made sure that I have the correct port and instance name

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, sql-server-2019, aws

Connection to SQL Server failed.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)